# React Variables Not Updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a state and reducer as so:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialAuthState);
```

I have a axios instance that I create like so:

```
const [client] = useState(() => {
const newAxios = axios.create();
newAxios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const local = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_LOCALSTORAGE_KEY);
  if (local === null) return config;
  const token = JSON.parse(local).access_token;
  if(!config.url?.includes(HOST_URL)) config.url = HOST_URL + config.url;
  if (token && config.headers !== undefined) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  dispatch({ type: "LOADING", value: true });
  return config;
});
newAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOADING", value: false });
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOADING", value: false });
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response === undefined) return Promise.reject(error);
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      await refreshToken();
      return newAxios(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
return newAxios;});
```

When I call the dispatch function to update the loading value it never updates and always remains the same, even if I use a standard variable with useState and update using setter it doesn't update either. What is going on?

Comment: Link to full file: https://github.com/John-Doherty01/docker-celery/blob/main/hitman-webapp/src/authentication/auth-provider.tsx#L59

Comment: Its like the axios intercept functions don't have any awareness of the variables values changing.

Comment: Have you set set up redux store for your app. I can't find it in your code.

Comment: @PR7 there's nothing in the code here which suggests that the app uses Redux at all. React's `useReducer` hook is just an alternative way of managing local component state using a reducer function - it's got nothing to do with Redux, or global state.

Comment: please post all relevant code in the actual question, not in offsite links. I don't see how the axios setup code is relevant, what should be relevant here is your reducer code, the places where you call `dispatch`, and anywhere you use the `state` that the reducer should update

Comment: @RobinZigmond I see, I was trying to find where the dispatched action is going from the code but couldn't find...

Comment: @RobinZigmond the dispatch calls the reducer method here: https://github.com/John-Doherty01/docker-celery/blob/main/hitman-webapp/src/authentication/reducer.ts#L8

Comment: @RobinZigmond if I follow it through it triggers and everything but when I evaluated the variable after the dispatch line is executed the variable value never changes? This gets called from the axios intercept function

Comment: don't worry if `console.log(state)` immediately after a `dispatch(...)` still shows the old value - that's completely normal and expected. The new `state` value won't "appear" in the code until the next render - but React ensures that happens soon. Is there actually a problem with how your component is behaving, or are you just asking about a console.log not showing what you expect?

Comment: @RobinZigmond first time using them, yep was doing a console log after a dispatch with the expectation of the value to change. Didn't know the component had to rerender